# What is Belgravia in 'a Scandal in Belgravia'?

Tags: analysis, title, sherlock

The title of the 1st episode on Season 2 of *Sherlock*, the TV-series is ***A scandal in Belgravia***. What is Belgravia?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is a very exclusive part of London, part of the [Royal Borough of Kensington and Chelsea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Borough_of_Kensington_and_Chelsea). It is named after [Belgrave Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgrave_Square), which today includes many international embassies to the UK.

It was used as an alternative UK based location for the original Arthur Conan Doyle story which was [A Scandal in Bohemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Scandal_in_Bohemia).  Belgravia was probably chosen because of the alliteration with the word 'Bohemia' and the reputation of the area as being a location of rich and powerful people, who Irene Adler (as a professional and very expensive dominatrix) might find clients.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I presume it's the [district in London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgravia) but I have not seen the episode, so I may not be correct.